# How do I get the last object array in MongoDB based on condition

Tags: mongodb

I want to query mongoDB Data:

```
mongoDBData: 
[{ cost: 1, productCode: "A"}],
[{ cost: 2, productCode: "A"}],
[{ cost: 3, productCode: "B"}],
[{ cost: 4, productCode: "A"}],
[{ cost: 5, productCode: "B"}],
[{ cost: 6, productCode: "A"}],
[{ cost: 7, productCode: "C"}],
[{ cost: 8, productCode: "C"}],
[{ cost: 9, productCode: "D"}],
[{ cost: 10, productCode: "D"}]
```

based on an array. This is the array:

```
mappedProductCode = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

This is my desired result:

```
desiredResult = [
{productCode: "A", cost: 6},
{productCode: "B", cost: 5},
{productCode: "C", cost: 8},
]
```

Here's how I did by making a loop:

```
productCost=[]
for (let i = 0; i < mappedProductCode.length; i++) {
const skuLoop = mappedProductCode[i];
      const skuCost = await PosCost.findOne({ productCOde: mappedProductCode[i] }).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1);
      const loopPrice = skuCost? skuCost.cost : 0;

      productCost[i] = {
        sku: skuLoop,
        cost: loopPrice
      };
    }
```

My desired result is still achieved but it is very slow, what do I do to improve the code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $match: {
  productCode: {
    $in: [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ]
  }
 }
},
{
  $sort: {
    productCode: 1,
    cost: -1
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$productCode",
    cost: {
      $first: "$cost"
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    productCode: "$_id",
    cost: 1,
    _id: 0
 }
},
{
  $sort: {
    productCode: 1
 }
}  
])
```

Explained:

1. $match the products that you need
2. $sort by productCode and descending cost
3. $group by productCode and get only the first cost from the descending order
4. $project the _id to the original key name "productCode"
5. $sort by needed final result order

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tRVLy6ktfAc)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed reply. I am sorry, my mongoDBData above was incorrect. I edited it to reflect to my correct MongoDB Collection. I hope you can help me again. Appreciate it!